# Having Issue On Getting alt of Closest Image to buttons

Tags: jquery

I have a set of panels includinf buttons and images , now I need to get the `alt` attribute of each image close to the clicked button

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right btn-delete-img" data-id="pmkLips">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="../img/pmkLips/img.png" class="img-responsive" alt="sample Data">
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried this

```
$(function() {
    $(".btn-delete-img").on("click", function(){
    var imgName =  $(this).next('img').attr('alt'); 
});
```

and

```
$(function() {
    $(".btn-delete-img").on("click", function(){
    var imgName =  $(this).find('img').attr('alt'); 
});
```

but I am getting

> img: undefined

in the console. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `.find()` looks BELOW the specified element, so you're searching for an image inside your `<button>`. there's no img there, so there's no `.next('img')` available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `closest('.panel')` to find ancestor `.panel` and then find `img` in it like following.

```js
$(".btn-delete-img").on("click", function () {
    var imgName = $(this).closest('.panel').find('img').attr('alt');
    alert(imgName);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right btn-delete-img" data-id="pmkLips">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true">Click</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="../img/pmkLips/img.png" class="img-responsive" alt="sample Data">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first traverse one level up the DOM with `.parent()` (or `.closest()`), then go to the next element with `.next()`, and then get the image with `.find()`:

```
$(".btn-delete-img").on("click", function(){
    var imgName =  $(this).parent().next().find('img').attr('alt'); 
    console.log(imgName)
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fhtpprL0/)**